# I am getting dereferencing to incomplete types every time i run this code

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void withdrawPtr(int);
typedef void depositPtr(int);
typedef void accountPtr(int);
typedef void deltaccountPtr();
int balance;
pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
```

i have actually converted an equivalent c++ code to c code

```
typedef struct 
{
   int (*read)();
   withdrawPtr *withdraw;
   depositPtr *deposit;
   accountPtr *account;
   deltaccountPtr *deltaccount;

} accountstrct;


 void  *WithdrawThread(void *param)
{
struct accountstrct*  Mystruct = (struct accountstrct*) param;
```

here i get dereferencing pointer to incomplete type. I am not getting how else shud icall the function withdraw here.?

```
Mystruct->withdrawPtr=*withdraw ;
Mystruct->withdrawPtr(2);
return 0;
   }
```

Comment: @Als: Headers don't prove anything. Question was tagged C++ before.

Answer (score 3):

You never defined `struct accountstrct`. Either define the type as `struct accountstrct { };` and reference the type using `struct accountstrct` or define the type as `typedef struct {} accountstrct;` and reference the type using `accountstrct` (not "struct accountscrct").

You currently have defined a type called `accountstrct` but you are trying to use a type called `struct accountstrct`.

Comment: He already does typedef struct {} accountstrct. His type is called "accountstrct", he should drop 'struct' to fix the compiler error.

Comment: +1, but the real "proper" solution is to have both `struct accountstrct` *and* the `typedef`, e.g by putting `typedef struct accountstrct accountstrct;` before the definition of the `struct` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got those `typedef`s to compile.  Put the `*` in there and make them proper function pointer definitions.  Then take out the `*` from the `struct` fields.  And on the bottom, `Mystruct` doesn't have a `withdrawPtr` field, you probably mean just `withdraw`.  Speaking of which, where is the `withdraw` it's being set to coming from?

Here's more what it should look like:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*withdrawPtr)(int);
typedef void (*depositPtr)(int);
typedef void (*accountPtr)(int);
typedef void (*deltaccountPtr)();
int balance;
pthread_mutex_t mutex1;

typedef struct 
{
   int (*read)();
   withdrawPtr withdraw;
   depositPtr deposit;
   accountPtr account;
   deltaccountPtr deltaccount;

} accountstrct;


void  *WithdrawThread(void *param)
{
  struct accountstrct*  Mystruct = (struct accountstrct*) param;
...

  Mystruct->withdraw = withdraw;
  Mystruct->withdraw(2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A typedef for a function type is perfectly legal.  You can't use it to declare or define a function, but you can use in other contexts.  For example: `void foo(void) { ... } ... typedef void func(void); func *ptr = foo; ptr();`

Comment: Interesting.  I tried it before I said that and it didn't compile.  Perhaps I made a typo.